# Единственный экземпляр программы python

Tags: python

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при повторном запуске программы вместо запуска нового экземпляра программы, показывалось окно уже открытой программы

Comment: Вы можете сохранять pid процесса в файл, и при открытии новой программы смотреть, работает ли сейчас процесс с таким pid. Функцию передачи фокуса на окно процесса с определённым pid можно найти в инете в зависимости от целевой платформы (windows\linux).

Comment: Линукс или виндовс?

Comment: винда...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте запись в какой-нибудь файл , к примеру в txt. Пример:

```
filename="save.txt"
if filename:
    print ("ТУТ ДЕЙСТВИЯ")
else :
    print ("ИДЕТ ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ КАКОЙ-НИБУДЬ ФУНКЦИИ, ГДЕ, В КОНЦЕ БУДЕТ НАПИСАНО ТАК - ")
    with open (filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write("Теперь у нас есть что-то типа сохранения")
```

Что же я сделал ? Получается, если у нас есть файл, то он будет неким сохранением. Мы Проверяем, есть ли у нас файл и дальше уже решаем - продолжать действие или начать новое